# Use a variable for filename in jsp include

Tags: jsp

I want to do something like this in a JSP file.

```
<%
    String s = (String)request.getAttribute("userid");
%>
<jsp:include  page='/<%=s%>.html' />
```

I've seen a few methods while searching for answers yet none have worked for me. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you try:

`<%
    String s = (String)request.getAttribute("userid");
%>
<jsp:include  page="<%= s %>.html" />`

I think whitespaces matter and don't think you should escape characters in include. 

What you're doing should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried this but it says "attribute for %>" is not properly terminated" I'm not sure how to make this work

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. it was supposed to have the .html inside the expression. This is an Edit: can you try: `<% String s = (String)request.getAttribute("userid"); %> <jsp:include page='<%= s + ".html" %>' />`

Comment: Oh nice, that worked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: glad i could help! i have added it as the official answer to the post.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try:

```
    <% String s = (String)request.getAttribute("userid"); %>

    <jsp:include  page='<%= s + ".html" %>' />
```

I think white spaces matter and also do string concatenation inside the expression tag.

Comment: I included a jsp here but page printed instead of executing